# The reason of enumerate (list) environment topsep doesn't applied when directly under a section heading

Tags: enumerate, afterheading

Here is an example. I use `enumitem` package to set the `topsep` for a `enumerate` environment. When the list is placed directly under a section heading, the `topsep` are ignored. I know this is probably related to the definition of some after heading settings in those heading command (e.g., `\chapter`, `\section`). Something to do with internal settings of `everypar`, `\if@noskipsec` and `\leavevmode` etc. But by looking at the source code, I can't not fully understand those settings. There is no wiki contents that are related this type of question either. At least, I didn't find one.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Example}

\section{space with text}
Here is some text that is placed above the list.

\begin{enumerate}[topsep=1cm]
\item one
\item two
\end{enumerate}

Here is some text that is placed below the list.

\section{space without text}

\begin{enumerate}[topsep=1cm]
\item one
\item two
\end{enumerate}

Here is some text that is placed below the list.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there anyone can explain in details that how the after heading settings are defined. And is there a way (without manually add `\vspace` or `\leavevmode`) to make the `topsep` be always included no matter where the list been placed. Also, keep the consistent `topsep` length no matter if it was placed directly under a section heading or not (Because, I saw the distance seems larger than the value I set if I manaully add a `\leavevmode` before the `enumerate` env direct under the heading).

Comment: you could try `\setlist{before=\vspace{1cm}}` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is by design (From Leslie Lamport going back to the earliest LaTeX releases)

`\@trivlist` does

```
\def\@trivlist{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \@topsepadd \topsep
  \ifvmode
    \advance\@topsepadd \partopsep
  \else
    \unskip \par
  \fi
```

so the list top sep only gets added in vmode but if you are just after a heading `\leavevmode` ensures that branch isn't taken,

Comment: I am still confused. To me the `\@topsepadd \topsep` was not in any of the condition statements. if we are not in vmode, the command `\advance\@topsepadd \partopsep` won't be executed, instead there will be `\unskip\par`. How this will influence the `\topsep` to be added?

Comment: @Tom there is no paragraph above so it would be partopsep which is added not topsep and this conditional is supressing that specifically if it is immediately following a section, but there are actually a few more conditional tests to consider I'll probably update with a longer walk through of the list code later.